# DataMember property 'relation key' cannot be found on the DataSource

Tags: c#, datasource, bindingsource, datamember

I currently have a DataSet that has several tables in it for a C# Windows app. I have one parent table and all of the other tables in this set are child tables that have a relation to the ID column in the parent.

I just recently added a new table and made the necessary relation to the parent table through the wizard and designer, not coding. However, when I go to my form and try to change the DataMember on the property screen of the BindingSource, it doesn't find the relation that I just created in the drop down menu. I try to manually input the name of the relation and I receive the error message listed in the title.

I've never had this issue before when I have added child tables to the DataSet and then changed the DataMembers for them so I'm not really sure where to go from here in order to resolve this issue. Any assistance would be awesome.

Let me know if you need more information.

Edit: I should also add that it seems to only be happening with this one DataSet. I tried adding the exact same table to a different DataSet I had and everything worked without an issue.